# route external IP hostname to Windows Server 2022 internal IP

Tags: networking, dns, windows-server

My server has a single NIC with 2 IP addresses.

192.168.1.8 and 192.168.1.9

- 1.8 is for Apache
- 1.9 is for IIS

From inside the network everything works fine, but from outside I get redirected to the hostname of the website in Apache, maybe because it's the first IP.

**Regardless of if I enter https or https I end up in the apache website, as seen in the vhsot config I posted the browser ends up in HTTPS since I have a 301 redirect in port 80.**

How do I make it so that from outside all traffic on ports 80 and 443 go to IIS on 192.168.1.9?

I tried firewall setting an inbound rule, selecting w3wp.exe and in Scope setting my external IP on remote IP address.

That did not work.

Do I have to add anything to the DNS manager? If needed I can add a picture of the tree shown in the DNS Admin tool.

Update:

In the router there's already NAT to the server's IP, `SERVER   80  80  TCP 192.168.1.9` and `SERVER    443 443 TCP 192.168.1.9` what's more it's to the correct IP address, the one IIS is listening on.

| Rule Name | External Port | Internal Port | Protocol | Internal IP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SERVER | 80 | 80 | TCP | 192.168.1.9 |
| SERVER | 443 | 443 | TCP | 192.168.1.9 |

[image]

IIS Sites listening on 192.168.1.9 80 and 443
[image]

Apache has:

- On `https.conf`:

  - `Listen 192.168.1.8:80`
- On `https-ssl.conf`:

  - `Listen 192.168.1.8:443`
- On `https-vhost.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.8:80>
    ServerName website.com
    ServerAlias website.com
    Redirect 301 / https://website.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.8:443>
    ServerName  website.com
    ServerAlias website.com

    # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/website/public"

    # Log file locations
    LogLevel warn

    ErrorLog "logs/website-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/website-access.log" common
    
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    C:\\Apache24\\certificates\\website.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile C:\\Apache24\\certificates\\website.com.key

    <Directory C:/Apache24/htdocs/website/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Cache for static resources (Enable expiration and set it to A2592000 = 1 month)
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
    ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
    ExpiresByType text/javascript A2592000
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A2592000

    # Compress returned resources of type php pages, text file export, css and javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript

    Protocols h2 http/1.1

</VirtualHost>
```

Ping to the domain works fine:

```
Haciendo ping a myname.myqnapcloud.com [1.2.3.4] con 32 bytes de datos:
Respuesta desde 1.2.3.4: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=64
Respuesta desde 1.2.3.4: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=64
Respuesta desde 1.2.3.4: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=64
Respuesta desde 1.2.3.4: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=64

Estadísticas de ping para 1.2.3.4:
    Paquetes: enviados = 4, recibidos = 4, perdidos = 0
    (0% perdidos),
Tiempos aproximados de ida y vuelta en milisegundos:
    Mínimo = 0ms, Máximo = 0ms, Media = 0ms
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149039/discussion-on-question-by-daviid-route-external-ip-hostname-to-windows-server-20); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.